# Fortran: initializing of and assigning value to arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, assign

To initialize and assign value to arrays in **Fortran** we do as the following:

**Initializing:**

```
real(kind=8):: r(3,4)
...
r(:,:) = 0.0_8
```

what if we use only

```
real(kind=8):: r(3,4)
...
r = 0.0_8
```

and what if we do as:

```
real(kind=8):: r(3,4)
...
r = 0
```

also for situation such as:

```
real(kind=8):: r(3,4), q(3,4), p(30,40)
...
q = 0
r = q
r = p(1:3,21:24)
```

we prefer to do as:

```
real(kind=8):: r(3,4), q(3,4), p(30,40)
...
q = 0.0_8
r(:,:) = q(:,:)
r(:,:) = p(1:3,21:24)
```

we are not sure so **hope you provide us some reasons for each one you prefer**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you think that "kind=8" means 8 bytes?   That isn't true for all compilers.  The maximum portability is achieved using the selected_real_kind intrinsic to define a kind value:

```
integer, parameter :: DRK = selected_real_kind (14)
```

Of some of the options that you list, I prefer
`r = 0.0_8`, or better `r=0.0_DRK`.
This defines the entire array.  There is no need to designate array sections in this case, since you are calling out the entire array: r (:, :).  Steve Lionel has a discussion of why trying to make arrays obvious with ":" isn't a good idea -- there are differences between *array* and *array (:)*.  As an argument, the first has it declared dimensions, while the second always begins at 1 -- see http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this/

Since *r* is real, *r=0* implies a conversion. For the value zero this almost certainly doesn't matter, but it could make an important difference with other values.  e.g.,

```
r = 3.1415927654
```

and

```
r = 3.141592654_8
```

will give different values to `r` because the constants are different, the first being converted to single precision before the assignment.

Comment: The part about kind=8 not being equivalent to 8 bytes has been discussed a lot in the past. It is somewhat of a general opinion that kind types should't have been designated with integers to begin with. It causes a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 12):

For general considerations (including declaration and assignation) about efficiently using arrays in Fortran, I would suggest to read [this](http://mvs.icc.ru/documentation/intel/f_ug2/prg_arrs.htm).

For more precise answer to your question, [I did some tests some months ago](http://maxlevesque.tumblr.com/post/10454287358/using-array-efficiently) that may interest you. Here are the results. This is a test on my personnal laptop on Linux Archlinux x86-64, with GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease) without optimization options.

```
do i = 1 , 100
  do j = 1 , 100
    do k = 1 , 100 ! innest is fastest
      array ( i , j , k ) = 0.0d0
    end do
  end do
end do
! reference time : 1.00
```

to

```
do i = 1 , 100
  do j = 1 , 100
    do k = 1 , 100
      array ( k , j , i ) = 0.0d0
    end do
  end do
end do
! time : 0.499
```

to

```
array = 0.0d0
! time : 0.250
```

to

```
array ( : , : , : ) = 0.0d0
! time : 0.250
```

Comment: Hi Max, the link to your work is broken. Moreover, I'm not sure what a comparison with optimization turned off would reveal. The inner loop here would optimize trivially. Often your examples 2,3,4 will be the same in optimized mode.

Comment: I guess the time difference is due to the way array is stored in memory. In Fortran, take 2 dimensional matrix for example, column vectors are stored continuously instead of row vectors which is the case of C++.